# Remove Focus change Listener of a view in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, onfocuschangelistener

> I have added **FocusChangeListener** to `EditText`. like

```
etZip.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(!hasFocus)
                {
                     callAreaDetailService(zipCode,false);
                }
            }
        });
```

Now If I have `focus` on `etZip` and I click on `Button` to go to **anotherActivity**. etZip loses focus and show Response alert in Next Activity.

I know I can add a `boolean` flag for not calling `service` if button is clicked. But I am sure there must be an `android` build in method to **stop focus change**.

There is no `function` like `etZip.removeFocusChangeListener` . So is there any way to do this using **Android SDK**.

Comment: "There is no `function` like `etZip.removeFocusChangeListener`" - You can set the listener to `null`.

Comment: @Mike M Then why android added removeTextChangeListener  instead of etZip.addTextChangedListener(null);

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking, but that's just how they designed it. An `EditText` can have multiple `TextWatcher`s, and it keeps a collection for them. Adding `null` to that collection won't remove any of them. An `EditText` can have only one `OnFocusChangeListener`, though, so setting it to `null` essentially removes it, if it had one.

Comment: Great explaination @MikeM.